# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I try to connect to server like EC2.

```
sudo ssh -i file.pem ec2-user@IP
```

But I can't connect it.

The error is:

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

How to connect to EC2?

Comment: This often indicates a network problem. Can you temporarily try this via a different network, such as home vs work, or even tethered via your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things that you should need to take a look first:

1) You should check your EC2 current usage: `CPU/Memory/DiskSpace` using **Amazon CloudWatch**. There are cases 100% usage on memory or root EBS volume which temporarily causes some laggy on your instance.

2) Simply reboot the EC2 instance if possible.

3) Check your security group and ensure your current public IP is whitelisted.